# How to get authorization for Google App scripts in my personal acccount only?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, authorization

Forgive if I've posted in the wrong place. I am a completely ignorant amateur but a year or so ago, following a cookbook, I managed to install 3 Google Apps scripts in the G Suite Developer Hub to delete tagged e-mail in my gmail account after x days.

The scripts have been running fine, but now I get a failure message:  "Authorization is required to perform that action."

I changed my password 2 days ago, I'm thinking that is the issue. I cannot see how the OAuth authorization applies to my scripts, which run only in my Google account and not on any Web site.

I am completely lost in the recursive Google documentation about authorization.

How do I fix this? How can I clear this error?

FYI, here is one of the scripts:

```
function cleanUp() {
  var delayDays = 2 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("TBD2");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you have encountered indicates that the script is [lacking the authorization needed to run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#authorization_is_required_to_perform_that_action). When a script is run in the Script Editor or from a custom menu item an authorization dialog is presented to the user. However, when a script is run from a trigger, embedded with a Google Sites page, or run as a service, the dialog cannot be presented and this error is shown.

This error is frequently caused by triggers that are firing before the user has authorized them. 
If a trigger continues to fire and cause this error, you can access your triggers by doing the following:

> 1. Select E**dit > All your triggers** in the Apps Script editor. The resulting dialog shows all active triggers running on your account.
> 2. Find the offending trigger in the list.
> 3. Click the clear icon next to the trigger name to remove it.
> 4. Click **Save** to record the deletion.

You can also remove problematic add-on triggers by [uninstalling the add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/install-addons#uninstalling_editor_add-ons).